# Putting the elements into new array from for loob Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm working on a Python 3 project. My code is more longer but I prepared for you a sample basic idea of my code which works.

```
arr = []
number = (["01", "02", "03", "06", "08"])
arr = number
pos1 = int(arr[1],16)
pos2 = 2 + int(arr[1],16)

for s in range(pos1,pos2):
  print(arr[s])
```

**Explanation:**
The numbers you see, they are hexadecimal numbers, I convert the `pos1` to `int` and  I add `2` on it with `pos2`. After a while I get output of `03 06`. I want to use these numbers in a different array. 
Is there any way put `03 06` into a new array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are intending. Are you interested in using `.append()` in loop?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Actually I want to take paremeter of `03` and `06` in the new array be like: `arr2 = []` and when I `print(arr2[0])` I want to see `03` only #pyd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then try this:

```
arr2 = []
number = (["01", "02", "03", "06", "08"])
arr = number[:]
pos1 = int(arr[1],16)
pos2 = 2 + int(arr[1],16)

for s in range(pos1,pos2):
    arr2.append(arr[s]) # add numbers to arr2
print(arr2[0])
```

Comment: Actually I want to take paremeter of `03` and `06` in the new array be like: `arr2 = []` and when I `print(arr2[0])` I want to see `03` only @RudolfMorkovskyi

Comment: @Asell I do not quite understand what you want) fixed the example, try again

Comment: Nope, Actually you totally understood, I want to see your fixed answer :) Thank you so much you safe my lfe

Answer (score 1):

you can use one liner:

```
newArr = [arr[s] for s in range(int(arr[1], 16), int(arr[1], 16) + 2)]
```